# Multipart post in grails causes 404 error

Tags: grails, file-upload

I try to upload data to a grails app. This works very good and the object is created in the database and the uploaded document is also present. Unfortunately i get a 404 error directly after the creation.

I am using grails 2.3.5 with the following code:

Action to save:

```
@Transactional
def save(Book bookInstance) {
    if (bookInstance == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    if (bookInstance.hasErrors()) {
        respond bookInstance.errors, view:'create'
        return
    }             


    if(!bookInstance.id){
        bookInstance.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
    }

    bookInstance.save flush:true


    request.withFormat {
        form {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'Book.label', default: 'Book'), bookInstance.id])
            redirect bookInstance
        }
        '*' { 
            respond bookInstance, [status: CREATED] 
        }
    }
}
```

GSP:

```
<g:uploadForm action="save" class="form-horizontal">
        <g:render template="form"/>

        <div class="form-actions margin-top-medium">
            <g:submitButton name="create" class="btn btn-primary" value="${message(code: 'default.button.create.label', default: 'Create')}" />
            <button class="btn" type="reset"><g:message code="default.button.reset.label" default="Reset" /></button>
        </div>
    </g:uploadForm>
```

When the  tag is used instead of the  it works. The enctype="multipart/form-data" causes the error.

What can I try to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Since grails 2.3.x you can use the request.withFormat (http://grails.org/doc/2.3.4/ref/Controllers/withFormat.html) rendering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check `conf/Config.groovy` and check that `multipartForm: 'multipart/form-data',` is present as a value for `grails.mime.types`, e.g.:

```
grails.mime.types = [
    ...
    form: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    multipartForm: 'multipart/form-data',
]
```

You also need to specify that it's a multipart form in your `withFormat` declaration:

```
request.withFormat {
    form multipartForm
```

Comment: Perfect! Adding the multipartForm in request.withFormat did it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

---

You can try 'render' or 'forward' instead of "respond" .